# What does "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel" mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I wrote a java program for school and it compiled properly but when I tried to run it I got this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel   at Main.main(Main.java:5) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 1 more

I have checked several sources but none match my exact problem. I use java version 11.0.2 and all this is being run on a mac and IDE is Atom.

> $ java -version java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

The exception means that the JavaFX components are not present in the classpath.

In java 11, javaFX has been moved outside the JDK.
[See for example this article.](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3305073/removed-from-jdk-11-javafx-11-arrives-as-a-standalone-module.html)

You need to download the javaFX module for your platform, and add it yourself.
[See those instructions.](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)